# How to escape unicode symbols in freemarker template processing?

Tags: unicode, freemarker, org.json

I'm using freemarker templates to convert JSON to XML. It works fine except when the input json contains some unicode symbols.
Till now I have encountered en-dash and em-dash and the FTL transformation fails with :
`lexical error: encountered "u" (117)`

The template fails when I'm using ?eval operation on a variable.

I'm using freemarker v2.3.28 and I have set encoding to UTF-8.

P.S. I checked that copyright and trademark symbols are working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is certainly that those characters are escaped in the source JSON as `\uXXXX`, but the FTL string syntax doesn't have `\u` escape. `?eval` interprets its input as FTL expression, not as a JSON expression. They happen to be similar, but there are differences. (BTW, to my knowledge, en-dash and em-dash need not be escaped in JSON, similarly to copyright, but of course it's allowed to escape any character.)

What to do? The FreeMarker-ish approach is adding the JSON to your data-model already parsed to `Map`-s (or Java beans) and `List`-s and such. The template isn't meant to parse input. If that's not feasible, then you could add your custom method to the data model (maybe as shared variable on the `Configuration`-level) which does real JSON parsing, and then you call it like `eval_json(x)`.

Anyway, what's the use case? The desire to parse JSON inside the template comes up often on SO. Maybe the next FreeMarker version should have a `?eval_json`, if the use case is valid.

Comment: How did this solve the issue? I'm asking because I'm still curious if `?eval_json` is a good idea, if there's a frequent and proper use case for it.

Comment: Thanks @ddekany !!
Earlier while I was trying out freemarker templates I just parsed the top level json objects and for any nested objects I used ?eval. That was working until I got these unicode symbols.
As per your suggestion now I'm parsing the entire JSON before passing it to the template and it's working fine.

Just out of curiosity, how do I check if those characters are escaped in the source JSON as \uXXXX ? I'm getting my json from elasticsearch directly.

Comment: ?eval_json would be nice though !
Now I'm just parsing the whole json to a Map and passing it to the template.

P.S: I confirmed that all the unicode symbols mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_symbols) are failing in my case.

Comment: @noobCoder I believe pre-parsing the whole JSON is the proper way. It's certainly easier than remembering to call `?eval_json` in the template. Or is it not?

Comment: @noobCoder As of the question, I'm note sure I understand it. You could search the string for `\u` that isn't preceded by a \ .

Comment: When I view the json in elasticsearch using the elasticsearch head plugin it shows normally and there's no escaping. I had also checked the json before passing to template and there was no escaping. I was guessing that the freemarker template might be escaping those. I had `<#ftl encoding='UTF-8'>` and `<#setting url_escaping_charset='UTF-8'>` set. Does that make any difference?

Comment: No, FreeMarker doesn't do such escaping (even if `?json_string` is applied somewhere, it doesn't escape en-dash and em-dash). Are you 100% sure that you have passed that JSON to the data-model as a Java `String` (as opposed to as some kind of Jackson JSON node object or such), and that it was that `String` that you have checked to not contain the `\uXXXX` escape? (UTF-8 is irrelevant.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual regarding [Expressions](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_direct_string), instead of `"\uHHHH"` you should use `"\xHHHH"` (**x** instead of **u**), where HHHH is one to four hexadecimal digits representing a [UCS](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/gloss.html#gloss.UCS).

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess the variable first by replacing all unicode to html entities.

```
replaceAll("\\\\u(....)", "&#x$1;")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this. Add the copyright symbol before the freemarker tag starts.

```html
<div class="copyrightLine">
    &copy;${getString("2022 Corporation. All rights reserved.")?html}
</div>
```